# How to split xml to header and items using smooks?

Tags: java, xml, smooks

I have a xml file roughly like this:

```
<batch>
    <header>
        <headerStuff />
    </header>
    <contents>
        <timestamp />
        <invoices>
            <invoice>
                <invoiceStuff />
            </invoice>
            <!-- Insert 1000 invoice elements here -->
        </invoices>
    </contents>
</batch>
```

I would like to split that file to 1000 files with the same headerStuff and only one invoice. Smooks documentation is very proud of the possibilities of transformations, but unfortunately I don't want to do those.

The only way I've figured how to do this is to repeat the whole structure in freemarker. But that feels like repeating the structure unnecessarily. The header has like 30 different tags so there would be lots of work involved also.

What I currently have is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<smooks-resource-list xmlns="http://www.milyn.org/xsd/smooks-1.1.xsd"    
    xmlns:calc="http://www.milyn.org/xsd/smooks/calc-1.1.xsd"
    xmlns:frag="http://www.milyn.org/xsd/smooks/fragment-routing-1.2.xsd"
    xmlns:file="http://www.milyn.org/xsd/smooks/file-routing-1.1.xsd">

    <params>
        <param name="stream.filter.type">SAX</param>
    </params>

    <frag:serialize fragment="INVOICE" bindTo="invoiceBean" />

    <calc:counter countOnElement="INVOICE" beanId="split_calc" start="1" />

    <file:outputStream openOnElement="INVOICE" resourceName="invoiceSplitStream">
        <file:fileNamePattern>invoice-${split_calc}.xml</file:fileNamePattern>
        <file:destinationDirectoryPattern>target/invoices</file:destinationDirectoryPattern>
        <file:highWaterMark mark="10"/>
    </file:outputStream>

    <resource-config selector="INVOICE">
        <resource>org.milyn.routing.io.OutputStreamRouter</resource>
        <param name="beanId">invoiceBean</param>
        <param name="resourceName">invoiceSplitStream</param>
        <param name="visitAfter">true</param>
    </resource-config>

</smooks-resource-list>
```

That creates files for each invoice tag, but I don't know how to continue from there to get the header also in the file.

EDIT:

The solution has to use Smooks. We use it in an application as a generic splitter and just create different smooks configuration files for different types of input files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just started with Smooks myself. However... your problem sounds identical to this: http://www.smooks.org/mediawiki/index.php?title=V1.5:Smooks_v1.5_User_Guide#Routing_to_File

You will have to provide the output FTL format in whole, that's the downside of using a general purpose tool I guess. Data mapping often includes a lot of what feels like redundancy, one way around this is to leverage convention but that has to be built into the framework.

Comment: I ultimately chose to go with recreating the xml stuff outside the split in the FTL template like you suggested. It wasn't what I was looking for and was a lot of work and prone to errors but I couldn't find anything else(it was a big schema). Maybe I'll create some cartridge to smooks to support cases like these if I need to do this multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know smooks, but the simplest solution (with poor performance) would be (to create the Nth file):

- copy the whole xml structure
- delete all the invoice tags but the Nth one

I don't know how to do that in smooks, that only an idea. In this case you don't need to duplicate the structure of the xml in a freemarker template.

Comment: The XML file can be gigabytes in size, that's why we are using smooks to split it because it uses event model that doesn't keep the whole file in memory.